# Use different type of cells and different number of rows in UITableViewController

Tags: ios, swift, uitableview

I am trying to use a UITableViewController(Static table view) with 4 sections and each has a different type of cell.

The number of cells in a section depends on the data received from the web service. In the storyboard, I have created one type of cell in each section.

```
override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // Number of rows in attachment sect
    if section == 2 {
        guard let currentDataModel = dataModel else { return 0 }
        return currentDataModel.attachments.count
    }
    else if section == 3 {
        guard let currentDataModel = dataModel else { return 0 }
        return currentDataModel.contacts.count
    }
    return super.tableView(tableView, numberOfRowsInSection: section)
}

override func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {
    let currentSection = indexPath.section
    if currentSection == 2 {

        let currentRow = indexPath.row
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "attachmentCell", for: indexPath) as! AttachmentViewCell
        cell.setDataForCell(dataModel: dataModel?.attachments[currentRow], indexPath: indexPath)
        return cell
    }
    //Show cells for Contact Section
    else if currentSection == 3 {
        let currentRow = indexPath.row
        let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "contactCell", for: indexPath) as! ContactViewCell
        cell.setDataForCell(dataModel: dataModel?.contacts[currentRow], indexPath: indexPath)
        return cell
    }
    return super.tableView(tableView, cellForRowAt: indexPath)
}
```

I am getting this error while calling dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:forIndexPath:

> Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSRangeException', reason: '*** -[__NSArrayI objectAtIndex:]: index 2 beyond bounds [0 .. 1]'

Can I Use the different type of cells and a different number of rows in each section in a UITableViewController?

Comment: Please share Some tried code Like array Info For sections , And cellforRow Main Code

Comment: error clearly says that you are truing to access third element in array of size 2. check your number of row in section returns proper number of rows

Comment: @Vinodh, Yes it returns the correct number of rows in the section.

Comment: Array Format Seems To be Wrong that is actually not coping up with Sections , I used a tableView With sections but only one cell for all sections if you want I can share that with you, else need to see array format

Comment: Which line does the crash occur on?

Comment: @Malik The crash happens on 'let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "attachmentCell", for: indexPath) as! AttachmentViewCell' for second row in the section.

Comment: @iOSGeek Can you check a different number of cells for all sections? But you need to have only one type of cell in the storyboard.

Comment: @vishalwaka That doesn't make sense. The line has nothing to do with arrays. The only errors this line could produce would be if the identifier was wrong or if the dequeued cell was not of the defined type

Comment: @malik here he showed errorindex 2 out of bounds means he is getting error in second section not in first section so it is actually a possible error of Array format

Comment: @vishalwaka I had used UITableView With Sections One common cell for All Sections , Static Data , With Number of rows differently in each section , Should I post my demo project here if you want maybe it help you

Answer (score 1):

Can you try this.If need a four sections then return 4 in `numberofsections`. You can add the title to each sections as below and later add it to label in `viewForHeaderInSection`.You must provide the number of rows in each sections correctly.

```
override func numberOfSectionsInTableView(tableView: UITableView) -> Int
    {
        return 4
    }


    override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, titleForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> String? {
        if(section == 0)
        {
            return "Section 0"
        }
        else if(section == 1)
        {
            return "Section 1"
        }
        else if(section == 2)
        {
            return "section 2"
        }
        else if(section == 3)
        {
            return "section 3"
        }
        return ""
    }

override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int {
    // #warning Incomplete implementation, return the number of rows

        switch(section)
        {
        case 0: //for first section
            //return your count

        case 1://Cells for

            //return your count

        case 2:

            //return your count

        case 3:
          //return your count

        default:
            return 4
        }

    return 0
}

    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) -> UITableViewCell {

        if indexPath.section == 0 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1", for: indexPath) as! Cell1

            return cell 

        } 
    else if indexPath.section == 1 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1", for: indexPath) as! Cell1

            return cell 

        }

 else if indexPath.section == 2 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1", for: indexPath) as! Cell1

            return cell 

        }

 else if indexPath.section == 3 {
            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell1", for: indexPath) as! Cell1

            return cell 

        }
else {

            let cell = tableView.dequeueReusableCell(withIdentifier: "cell2", for: indexPath) as? Cell2
            //Set up labels etc.
            return cell!
        }
    }

 override func tableView(tableView: UITableView, viewForHeaderInSection section: Int) -> UIView? {
    let headerView = UIView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: tableView.frame.width, height: 50))
    headerView.layer.borderWidth = 2
    let myLabel = UILabel()
    myLabel.frame = CGRectMake(0, 0, tableView.frame.width - 70, 50)
    myLabel.font = UIFont.boldSystemFontOfSize(18)
    myLabel.textColor = UIColor.whiteColor()
    myLabel.textAlignment = .Left
    myLabel.text = "  " + self.tableView(tableView, titleForHeaderInSection: section)!
    headerView.addSubview(myLabel)
    return headerView
}
```

If you are using .xib file then you should also register that file in `viewDidLoad()` as

```
self.tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "cell1", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell1")

self.tableView.registerNib(UINib(nibName: "cell2", bundle: nil), forCellReuseIdentifier: "cell2")
```